# Freeze Delegated Account Not working in Anchor program

Tags: metaplex, associated-token-account, freeze-token-account

[image: This is the code snippet from the anchor program I am working on to freeze token account]

I have been trying to freeze the token account by using freeze delegated account in an anchor program, but no matter what I try its not working. The latest update in my trial gives me 0x39. I can't figure out how to resolve this issue and run this function successfully.

Comment: please replace this screenshot with a code block

Comment: please post the full error message with transaction logs

Comment: Also, please provide more context, including the program and library that you're using.

Answer (score 3):

First there is a conceptual issue, why do you need to freeze the token in the holder wallet while he would be able to unfreeze it as being the one with the delegated_amount?

This is because the approved authority is `owner`.

The second issue is that you are providing the token program in place of the NFT edition (master edition or edition in there) in the call to `freeze_delegated_account`

This is the line that is incorrect `edition: ctx.accounts.token_program.key()`, it should be the edition PDA as

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/3a9c68ab8c48318f96379a136feaa9b66c322752/token-metadata/program/src/pda.rs#L5-L16

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. What is the NFT Edition? and I am freezing the token in holder wallet just to make it work somehow, if I pass this case I ll move to the next case.

Comment: I edited my answer to accuratly describe why the line is wrong